# DataContextChanged on a TreeView to trigger a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, runtime, datacontext

I have a **User** and a **Manager**, and the user has a **To-Do-List** with tasks that have been assigned to them. The manager has Users names as labels on there main screen and below that a number of tasks that are in their To-Do-List.

My objective is whenever the Users gets assigned a task in their To-Do-List, it instantly triggers a method at Runtime on the manager screen that counts the tasks in the users To-Do-List and updates their label on the managers page.

I don't know where to start on this task, hence why I am asking this question.

*I am not asking for all the code or any for that point just to be told how I can achieve what I want and I can work and figure the rest out for myself.*